# NoClassDefFoundError: HSSFWorkbook

Tags: java

I am trying the process Excel worksheet using MapReduce program. I have written the ExcelParser and there is no compile time error. But When I am running it it throws the below error.

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook
    at indiaweather.ExcelParser.parseExcelData(ExcelParser.java:20)
    at indiaweather.ExcelRecordReader.initialize(ExcelRecordReader.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 11 more
```

I have added the required jar files. Below is my ExcelParser Program.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class ExcelParser {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ExcelParser.class);
    private StringBuilder currentString = null;
    private long bytesRead = 0;

    public String parseExcelData(InputStream is) {
        try {
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(is);

            // Taking first sheet from the workbook
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
            currentString = new StringBuilder();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();

                // For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        bytesRead++;
                        currentString.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        bytesRead++;
                        currentString.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        bytesRead++;
                        currentString.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;

                    }
                }
                currentString.append("\n");
            }
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("IO Exception : File not found " + e);
        }
        return currentString.toString();

    }

    public long getBytesRead() {
        return bytesRead;
    }

}
```

I have added poi-3.13 jar in Buildpath. I did search in google but none of solutions couldnt fix the problem. I tried adding old versions of jar file also. But Nothing helps.

Comment: did you package all dependencies in one jar that you run?

Comment: Yes.  I will try adding poi-ooxml.jar and poi-ooxml-schemas-jar and check as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You may have added the jar to the build path, which makes the code compile, but it also needs to be on the Java classpath for it to work when you run it.

If you're running it from the command line, use the `-classpath` switch with the `java` command to add the jar. You can also add it to the `CLASSPATH` environment variable on your system.

Comment: I tried adding the jar file to classpath, but still getting error

Comment: `hadoop jar <jarfile where main class resides> -libjar <thirdpartyjar file> <input> <output>`  @KLibby

Comment: Can you also show the value of your classpath variable and update your question with these and the command you pasted in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 2 more jar files...`poi-ooxml.jar` and `poi-ooxml-schemas-jar`. Hope this helps...

Comment: I tried adding the mentioned xmls but nothing helps.